# Sending Email and printing report conflicts in odoo 10

Tags: python, python-2.7, email, printing, odoo-10

I am new in odoo. I am referring to some module on addons in odoo but this time i didn't found the answer. Anw my problem is I have send email and print button. The print button works well but my send email button is not and the error said:

```
File "/home/FlexERP/git/FlexERP/addons/report/models/report.py", line 178, 
in get_pdf
html = self.with_context(context).get_html(docids, report_name, data=data)
   File "/home/FlexERP/git/FlexERP/addons/report/models/report.py", line 
135, 
  in get_html
   return report_model.render_html(docids, data=data)
  File "/home/FlexERP/bitbucket/etsi-
addons/etsi_asset/reports/handover_report.py", line 9, in render_html
    docs = self.env[self.model].browse(self.env.context.get('active_id'))
  File "/home/FlexERP/git/FlexERP/FlexERP/api.py", line 752, in __getitem__
    return self.registry[model_name]._browse((), self)
  File "/home/FlexERP/git/FlexERP/FlexERP/modules/registry.py", line 174, 
in __getitem__
    return self.models[model_name]
KeyError: None
```

this is my handover_report.py that triggers an error

```
from odoo import fields, api, models

class HandoverReport(models.AbstractModel):
    _name = 'report.etsi_asset.handover_info_temp'

@api.multi
def render_html(self, docids, data=None):
    self.model = self.env.context.get('active_model')
    docs = self.env[self.model].browse(self.env.context.get('active_id'))

    print 'docs', docs

    docargs = {
        'doc_ids': docids,
        'doc_model': 'asset.management.handover',
        'docs': docs,
    }

    return self.env['report'].render('etsi_asset.handover_info_temp', 
    docargs)
```

BUT if I comment my codes in handover_report.py, my send email button works well

It said that this line

```
line 9, in render_html docs = 
self.env[self.model].browse(self.env.context.get('active_id'))
```

is an error but I didn't find what's wrong with that codes? can anybody 
explain me why. Anw I'm still working on it. Finding someone can help me. 
Many thanks. Again, I am newbie in odoo.

Answer (score 0):

You can try render_html like this...

```
@api.model
    def render_html(self, docids, data=None):
        self.model = self.env.context.get('active_model')
        user = self.env["res.users"].browse(self._uid)
        docargs = {
            'doc_ids': self.ids,
            'doc_model': self.model,
            'docs': user,
        }
        return self.env['report'].render('custom_reports.report_salereport', values=docargs)
```